# possible prefixes for bundle.getLocation()

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I'm using the Equinox OSGi implementation. When I retrieve a bundle and ask it for its location (getLocation() method) the returned String is prefixed with "initial@reference". The OSGi 4.3 specification does not mention this prefix. Is there another document where this prefix and other possible prefixes are specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are Equinox specific URL prefixes (although the reference: prefix is also supported by other OSGi Frameworks). They are not a part of OSGi Spec. From Eclipse Runtime Options:

> osgi.bundles
>       The comma-separated list of bundles which are automatically installed and optionally started once the system is up and running. Each entry is of the form:

```
    <URL | simple bundle location>[@ [<start-level>] [":start"]]
```

> The start-level indicates the OSGi start level at which the bundle should run. If the start-level (>0 integer) is omitted then the framework will use the default start level for the bundle. If the "start" tag is added then the bundle will be marked as started after being installed. Simple bundle locations are interepreted as relative to the framework's parent directory. If the location is not a fully qualified path or URL then a search is done to find the highest version available. Note that the reference: protocol can only be used to refer to content specified by a file: URL (e.g. reference:file:/path/to/mybundle_1.0.0.jar). If the bundle is a directory bundle then using a file: URL without the use of reference: is not supported (e.g. file:/path/to/myDirectoryBundle_1.0.0/ must use reference:file:/path/to/myDirectoryBundle_1.0.0/)

[here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/164404/) is a thread with description of "initial" and "reference" prefixes.

Comment: Thanks that brought some light into that topic

Answer (score 5):

The location can be pretty much anything. If I install a bundle as follows...

```
InputStream data = ...; // open a stream from wherever
context.installBundle("crazy location huh?", data);
```

... then subsequently the `getLocation()` method for this bundle will return "crazy location huh?".

This would only create problems for me if I tried to call the no-arg variant of `Bundle.update()`, since the framework would not be able to interpret the location string in order to update the bundle from that location. But I could always call the `Bundle.update(InputStream)` method to update the bundle from data that I specify directly.